# Android Widget View in Fragment getting IllegalStateException in Rx Subscription

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a couple IllegalStateExceptions which are occurring at times due to `this.progressContainer` being null.  In general that seems basically impossible but I'm worried I'm making a false assumption on how these lifecycle events are working.  I feel like its not necessary to do this defensive checking in this case, as it should be guaranteed on `onActivityCreated`.  There is definitely some brevity here which I'm not showing so if this isn't a complete enough picture to reason with the issue I have, please comment and I'll further complete the picture.

In general in the viewModel I use the following           `showProgressIndicator.onNext(true)` to control the progressContainer's visibility during network load times.

```
class OrdersFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = OrdersFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: OrdersViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OrdersViewModel::class.java)

               viewModel.orders
            .doOnError { Log.println(Log.WARN, "Orders", "Not found") }
            .doOnNext { Log.println(Log.WARN, "Orders", it.newOrders.toString()) }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map { orders ->
                val newOrders =
                orders.newOrders.map { order ->
                    OrderItemViewType.OrderRow(order, OrderType.NEW_ORDERS)
                }
                val enteredOrders = orders.enteredData.map { order ->
                    OrderItemViewType.OrderRow(order, OrderType.ENTERED_ORDERS)
                }
            }
            .subscribe { orders ->
                this.orders.clear()
                this.orders.add(0, OrderItemViewType.Header(OrderType.NEW_ORDERS, orders.newOrders.size))
                this.orders.addAll(orders.newOrders)
                this.orders.add(OrderItemViewType.Header(OrderType.ENTERED_ORDERS, orders.enteredOrders.size))
                this.orders.addAll(orders.enteredOrders)
                ordersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            .addTo(this.disposeBag)

        viewModel.shouldShowProgress
            .map {
                if(it) {
                    View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                //Avoiding the following crash for now
                //https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/blazebites-e21f4/crashlytics/app/android:com.blazebite.kitchen2/issues/9c3a41b85fe4e94dd8adee3c6bde185a?time=1581379200000:1581465599000&sessionId=5E403F3F006000013B9F7D10397BD681_DNE_0_v2
                if(this.progressContainer != null) {
                    this.progressContainer.visibility = it
                }
            }
            .addTo(this.disposeBag)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        this.disposeBag.dispose()
    }
}
```

Then the ViewModel

```
class OrdersViewModel : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {
    private val showProgressIndicator: PublishSubject<Boolean> = PublishSubject.create()
    val shouldShowProgress: Observable<Boolean>

    init {
        shouldShowProgress = showProgressIndicator

               orders = Observable
            .interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnNext { logger.write("Orders", "Attempting Order Retrieval") }
            .doOnNext { showProgressIndicator.onNext(true) }
            .filter { persistence.isLoggedIn }
            .doOnNext { logger.write("Orders", "Logged In") }
            .filter { persistence.accessToken.isNotEmpty() }
            .doOnNext { logger.write("Orders", "Have a valid token") }
            .filter { persistence.restaurantId > 0 }
            .flatMap { this.fullOrderData() }
            .doOnError { logger.write("Orders", "Might have been a bad request") }
            .doOnNext { showProgressIndicator.onNext(false) }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.progressContainer?.visibility = it`

Comment: I agree this is more succinct, I just want to understand why I need this in the first place.  Based on what I understand regarding the lifecycles and rx, I don't understand how this with the kotlin synthetic bindings is a problem.

Comment: The view is destroyed before onDestroy